# When are thread function local variables allocated with Posix?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I know it's a very specific question and it's not very interesting for a high level programmer, but I would like to know when exactly are allocated the local variables of a thread function, in other words after

```
pthread_create(&thread, &function, ...)
```

is executed, can I say that they exists in memory or not (considering that the scheduler could have not executed the thread yet)? 
I tried to search in the posix library code but it's not easy to understand, I arrive at the `clone` function, written in assembly, but than I cannot find che code of the system call service routine `sys_clone` to understand what exactly it does. I see in the `clone` code the invocation of the thread function, but I think this should happen only in the created thread (which could have never been executed by the scheduler when pthread_create is terminated) and not in the creator.

Comment: For gcc, thread local storage (TLS) is allocated in the thread stack memory, so exists as soon as the stack is allocated.  Note that the stack size in the pthread attributes must be large enough to include the TLS.

Comment: @stark, the local variables of a thread function are not at all the same thing as TLS.

Comment: Obviously, local variables of a function are allocated on the stack at entry to the function whether it is a thread or not.  I assumed this was not what the OP meant to ask.

Comment: `auto` variables have block scope, so you are not supposed to care. At the return of pthread_create they may, or may not, exist (probably not - the thread exists but has not yet begun executing)

Answer (score 3):

> in other words after
>
> ```
> pthread_create(&thread, &function, ...)
> ```
>
> is executed, can I say that they exists in memory or not (considering
>   that the scheduler could have not executed the thread yet)?

POSIX does not give you any reason for confidence that the local variables of the initial call to function `function()` in the created thread will have been allocated by the time `pthread_create()` returns.  They might or might not have been, and indeed, the answer might not even be well defined inasmuch as different threads do not necessarily have a consistent view of machine state.

There is no special significance to the local variables of a thread's start function relative to the local variables of any other function called in that thread.  Moreover, although `pthread_create()` will not return successfully until the new thread has been created, that's a separate question from whether the start function has even been entered, much less whether its local variables have been allocated.